# how to read each line from a .dat file in unix?

Tags: linux, unix

trade.dat is my file which consists of lines of data.

i have to concatanate each line of that file with comma (,)

help me please

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you mean just add a comma to the end of each line:

```
sed 's/$/,/' <oldfile >newfile
```

If you mean join all lines together into one line, separating each with a comma:

```
awk '{printf "%s,",$0}' <oldfile >newfile
```

Or the more correct one without a trailing comma (thanks, @hacker, for pointing out the error):

```
awk 'BEGIN {s=""} {printf "%s%s",s,$0;s=","}' <oldfile >newfile
```

If you want the output of any of those in a shell variable, simply use the `$()` construct, such as:

```
str=$(awk 'BEGIN {s=""} {printf "%s%s",s,$0;s=","}' <oldfile)
```

I find it preferable to use `$()` rather than backticks since it allows me to nest commands, something backticks can't do.

Comment: Except for that (awk) would give you a trailing comma.

Comment: ya superb solution its working, but i want to capture the output to a variable.

Answer (score 2):

Two obligatory `perl` versions (credit goes to [William Pursell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/140750/william-pursell) for the second one):

```
perl -i -p -e 'chomp($_); $_ = "$_,\n"' trade.dat

perl -i -p -e 's/$/,/' trade.dat
```

Note that

- this does not make backups of the original file by default (use `-i.bak` for that).
- this answer appends a comma to every line. To join all lines together into a single line, separated by commas, look at [William Purcell's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1320955/how-to-read-each-line-from-a-dat-file-in-unix/1321598#1321598).

Comment: Equivalent: perl -ipe 's/$/,/'

Comment: @William Pursell: Thanks - very nice. Note that you can't combine the -e option flag in this way though; it needs its own '-'.

Comment: Not quite. You're forgetting that -i swallows the rest of its argument to use as a backup extension. The most succinct you can get is `perl -pi -e 's/$/,/'`

Answer (score 1):

try

```
fullline=""
for line in $(cat trade.dat)
do
         fullline="$fullline,$line"
done
```

And then use $fullline to show youe file concatenated

hope this'll helps ;p

Comment: I'd be careful with this and huge files... you'll be filling up your memory in no time.

Comment: that is one thing to take care of, but musicking says he wants to use the whole as a variable ...

Answer (score 1):

```
perl -pe 's/\n/,/ unless eof'
```

Answer (score 0):

First thing that comes into my head:

> `gawk -- '{ if(a) { printf ",%s",$0; } else { printf "%s",$0; a=1 } }' trade.dat`

if I correctly understand what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Answering the question in the title, one way to get each line in a variable in a loop in BASH is to:

```
cat file.dat | while read line; do echo -n "$line",; done
```

That will leave a trailing comma, but shows how to read each line.

But clearly a sed or awk or perl solutions are the best suited to the problem described in the body of your question.